# Check if parameter is null in RDLC

Tags: c#, rdlc

I created a Report Viewer and I send it a parameter, but if the parameter is null it shows `#Error`. I tried this:

```
 =IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!frompay.Value),"Empty",FormatDateTime(Parameters!frompay.Value,DateFormat.ShortDate))
```

but the problem persists.

Comment: the text box shaw like this `#Error`

Comment: What is the type of `frompay`?

Comment: DateTime I take it from data time picker

Comment: Does https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11840.ssrs-iif-function-evaluates-both-true-false.aspx help?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

`IIf` executes [**both**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11840.ssrs-iif-function-evaluates-both-true-false.aspx) the `true` and `false` branches.

As such, `FormatDateTime(Parameters!frompay.Value,DateFormat.ShortDate)` tries to format `null`/`Nothing` as a date (which fails).

You likely need to do something like:

```
=IIf(IsDate(Parameters!frompay.Value), FormatDateTime(
CDate(iif(isdate(Parameters!frompay.Value),Parameters!frompay.Value,"01/01/1900")),
DateFormat.ShortDate),
"Empty")
```